# Is it appropriate to ask what the signs near the tomb of Abraham have written upon them, and some of the history behind those signs?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was recently reading up on Wikipedia regarding the Tomb of the Patriarchs, and was particularly interested in this picture: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Cenotaph_of_Abraham_-_northwestern_view.JPG

I'd like to learn about the signs with Hebrew writing (on what seems to be black velvet?) and the history behind them. Would it be appropriate to ask such a question on the main site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Jewish shrine, and you want to know about the meaning and history of the Judaism-oriented hangings there. This is 100% about Judaism, and 100% on-topic.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me to be just over the fine line of on vs off topic.

However, if you tweak it to ask why those quotes particularly are there, and what they mean, that sounds to be within the guidelines.

Unless that's what "history behind them" means, in which case, yes.